# HTML 'onclick' event shows 'Content not found' before going to desired href

Tags: html, button, onclick, http-status-code-404

I am using a button control through following code and observing a strange behavior. On my page when I click this button it momentarily shows a 'Content not found' page and then goes to the url specified in href. Any ideas? I am guessing 'Content not found' means 404? Why is it showing only briefly?

My basic objective is to go to another page on my website once this button is pressed. Any other ideas which may work smoothly?

```
<input class="application_button" type="button" onclick="location.href='http://myurl'" value="Button text" />
```

Comment: Why are you using `input` and not `button`?

Comment: try using onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')" instead of location.href=....

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<form action="http://myurl">
<input type="button" value="Button text">
</form>
```

Or this-

```
<input class="application_button" type="button" onclick="location.href('http://');" value="Button text">
```

Comment: Somehow none of the above mechanisms are working. Tried all the suggestions and it now only gets stuck at 'Content not found' page itself and does not go further. Earlier it was going to the desired URL although after a bit pause at 'Content not found'...